# How do I tell ReSharper that an attribute means that a method is used?

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

I'm playing with [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/), and ReSharper thinks that my step definitions are unused (I guess because they're used via reflection):

```
[Binding]
public class StepDefinitions
{
    // ...

    [When(@"I press add")]
    public void WhenIPressAdd()   // R# thinks this is unused
    {
        _calculator.PressAdd();
    }

    // ...
}
```

How can I tell ReSharper that methods with `[Given]`, `[When]`, `[Then]` attributes (etc.) are actually used? I don't want to use `// ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global` comments.

I could also mark each method (or the whole class) with `[JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitly]`. I don't particularly want to do that either.

Comment: Oddly, on another computer, R# doesn't warn about the 'unused' methods. Is there a configuration setting I could have changed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use JetBrains Annotations, and mark the attribute with an `MeansImplicitUseAttribute`.  You can either reference `JetBrains.Annotations.dll` directly, or you can copy the annotations source code (from *ReSharper* / *Options* / *Code Inspection* / *Code Annotations*) into your solution.

If you need to annotate some external assembly you don't own, you need to create an External Annotation file (xml) in the following folder: `%ReSharperInstallDir%\Bin\ExternalAnnotations`. There are plenty of examples, you can just copy some.

The external annotations file can also be in the same path as the DLL if you name it `DllNameWithoutExtension.ExternalAnnotations.xml`.

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to create an External Annotation file (xml) in the following folder: %ReSharperInstallDir%\Bin\ExternalAnnotations. There are plenty of examples, you can just copy some.

Comment: @IlyaRyzhenkov is there any way to deploy external annotations with the library (I do not want to inline or reference the JetBrains.Annotations.dll assembly) with no forcing user to place these annotations into %ReSharperInstallDir%\Bin\ExternalAnnotations  folder?

Comment: The external annotations file can also be in the same path as the DLL if you name it `DllNameWithoutExtension.ExternalAnnotations.xml` - works perfectly for my library. I have this file as part of my C# project and set it to be copied to the output directory on build.

Comment: Is there something like `MeansCanBeNull`? I have a custom attribute, and I want R# to treat it as its `CanBeNull` attribute.

Answer (score 10):

There are plenty of examples, but I wanted to be a little more explicit in case you don't want to track down an example. :)

Create a file with the name of the attribute's assembly (.xml) in %ReSharperInstallDir%\Bin\ExternalAnnotations. For example, I made Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.xml and put this XML inside it:

```
<assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework">
  <member name="T:Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.MeansImplicitUseAttribute.#ctor" />
  </member>
</assembly>
```

Restart VS and you're on your way!

Answer (score 0):

these answers have helped but note worthy if you are looking to decorate an interface you will want to use the `UsedImplicitly` attribute

```
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        //... stuff
    }
```